# How can I display incoming e-mail addresses (in my searches)?

Tags: gmail, google-contacts

I checked the first four search result pages on Web Applications and Google, but I didn't find an answer to my question and issue, which is also discussed [on the Google Help forums by other people](https://groups.google.com/a/googleproductforums.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/4ngN8VrAaRc).

My issue is, I know from people that they might have more than one e-mail address, but I don't remember it, as most people use cryptic e-mail addresses, even older folks. Now when I search for a person, e.g. in this screenshot:

[image: Gmail Search screenshot]

It doesn't help me to display and **find** the e-mail address of this guy. Important: **I might not have saved this e-mail address of him to my contacts** yet, thus it doesn't help me to search my Google Contacts! Also, if you don't want me to use Greplin, switching over to Google Contacts is another (time-consuming) step that I want to avoid.

And then of course there is the issue described in the Google help thread: Sometimes I simply want or need to see the e-mail address, even if obtaining it is not the problem.

I checked my IMAP client (Postbox 3), but their search is actually worse in regards to my goal.

Conclusion: As I am using several browser extensions that alter and expand the display and features of Gmail, I wonder if there isn't a browser (Chrome) extension also for this issue?

Answer (score 1):

If you hover your mouse pointer over one of the names, you'll get a "contact card" which will show you the email address. (Plus other information if the person is actually in your contacts.)

[image: contact card]